# Android - Get another installed App's savedInstance

Tags: android, instance, root

Is it possible to get another insalled app's savedInstance data? I need the RAM data/activity data of another app. Lets say the other app is a simple Activity with an EditText. Am i able to get the text the user has entered?
I guess it's not possible on stock Android, but is there a way with root permissions to achieve this ?

For real, i don't want to steal any passwords/informations from the user. I want to create an app to push an active Application to another device with the same data.

Comment: "I guess it's not possible on stock Android" -- correct.

Comment: @CommonsWare but it is possible with root ?